# std::ptr::Unique has no method named offset

Tags: pointers, rust

When I try to compile the following code using the nightly compiler, I get an error:

```
#![feature(alloc)]
#![feature(unique)]
#![feature(heap_api)]
extern crate alloc;

use std::ptr::{Unique, self};
use alloc::heap;
use std::mem;

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let align = mem::align_of::<i32>();
        let elem_size = mem::size_of::<i32>();
        let ptr = heap::allocate(elem_size*5, align);
        let a = Unique::new(ptr as *mut _);
        println!("{}", *a.offset(2));
    }
}
```

Error:

```
rustc 1.19.0-nightly (5de00925b 2017-05-29)
error: no method named `offset` found for type `std::ptr::Unique<_>` in the current scope
  --> <anon>:16:27
   |
16 |         println!("{}", *a.offset(2));
   |                           ^^^^^^
```

According to the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/struct.Unique.html#method.offset), `offset` should be defined for `Unique`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems that documentation wasn't updated. In latest nightly `Unique<T>` doesn't implement `Deref<Target=*mut T>`. You can use `*a.as_ptr().offset(2)` instead. `Unique` isn't stable yet, so changes are to be expected.

Comment: The latest nightly doc can be found in https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/ptr/struct.Unique.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are reading outdated docs compared to the code you are using. The most up-to-date nightly APIs can be found at [https://doc.rust-lang.org/**nightly**/std/ptr/struct.Unique.html](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/ptr/struct.Unique.html).

Previously, `Unique` got the `.offset()` method via the `Deref` trait to `*mut T`. This `Deref` impl was removed on [2017 May 6th](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/41064) because

> Major difference is that I removed `Deref` impls, as apparently **LLVM has trouble maintaining metadata with a `&ptr -> &ptr` API**. This was cited as a blocker for ever stabilizing this API. It wasn't that ergonomic anyway.

Nowadays to get the `*mut T`, you call [`.as_ptr()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/ptr/struct.Unique.html#method.as_ptr). This is a value-to-value, not reference-to-reference function, thus works around the LLVM issue.

```
println!("{}", *a.as_ptr().offset(2));
//                ^~~~~~~~
```